# Creality Ender 3 Pro 3D Printer

Tags: creality-ender-3, hotend, heat-management

I have an Ender 3 Pro with 4.2.2 controller board and BLTouch fitted, currently running Marlin Bugfix 2.0 firmware.

I needed to fit a new printer hot end and thermistor, but now the temperature is going wild and fluctuates up and down substantially from the pre-set temperature. The printer won't print and after a short time of E heating, it then displays an error.

I have looked at every video I can find and all the instructions I can find as to how to fix the problem and do a PID autotune but none of them match my firmware. I don't have the commands they say to go to. Creality must have released hundreds of different versions and none of what I can find match mine.

Can someone please give me detailed instructions on how I might be able to fix the problem. Most instructions I see on the web leave out at least 50 % of what you need to know. They tell you to go to certain commands in the firmware but in most cases those commands do not exist in mine. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please better explain in more details: `but now the temperature is going wild and fluctuates up and down`.  When does this happen, possible make photos or a video and share this. It is really hard to understand what is going on with your machine with the current description.